# XCode 15.0 can't find 'assert.h'

Tags: xcode

I can't build C project with XCode 15.0, error: 'assert.h' file not found
Source: #include <assert.h>

Ventura 13.6, M2

I tried to clean build folder, restart XCode, reinstall XCode, set different project format and deployment target.
I found also all entries of stdarg.h with Finder and made sure, that all directories, containing stdarg.h, contain also assert.h, but stdarg.h includes are resolved, assert.h - not. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem seems to be solved. The availability of different header files depends on XCode project type. Header files, available for app or console solutions, may be not accessible in IOKit or KExt projects.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running on `simulator`, please try below steps.

1. Clean the project
2. select device `Any simulator device (x86_64)`
3. if build successfully then select you're preferred device type